# Highlighting with regex within ssh session?

Tags: command-line, highlighting

I'm working with a lot of routers and switches from Juniper, Brocade etc and none of those vendors have syntax highlighting or output coloring.

Does anyone know a working solution: how to setup regexes on my local bash, which will colorize my remote ssh session?

I tried [grc](https://github.com/pengwynn/grc) recently. This works in a basic way, but with this I don't see my input until I hit Enter.

I'm especially searching for a solution which highlights MAC addresses, IP addresses and some other outputs such as route preferences, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. Unfortunately it requires recompilation of ssh client, but it works well.

https://github.com/mxtommy/Cisco-SSH-Client